# Request for seismic data annotated with Earthquake/NoEarthquake labels

Tags: data-request

I tried searching (and failed to find) annotated times series of seismic data. More specifically, I'm interested in seismic data time series that would have labels like "earthquake", "no earthquake", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure what you mean by time series data for earthquakes. If it is continuously measured seismicity at a single spot, I haven't found that.

What I currently found though is data about occurrence of

- [earthquakes](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?xml=NOAA/NESDIS/NGDC/MGG/Hazards/iso/xml/G012153.xml&view=getDataView&header=none)
- [tsunamis](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?xml=NOAA/NESDIS/NGDC/MGG/Hazards/iso/xml/G02151.xml&view=getDataView&header=none) (with flag for earthquake-induced)
- [volcanic eruptions](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?xml=NOAA/NESDIS/NGDC/MGG/Hazards/iso/xml/G10147.xml&view=getDataView&header=none)

Maybe it helps.